# Tablesort sort a column of ints and strings

Tags: types, tablesorter

I have a problem where my tablesorter column contains data that looks like this, [20823, C420837, 9823927, 47-123, C47293] along with blank spaces that are NoneType
the problem is when I try to sort them (asc, or desc) my tablesort groups all the number types together then the rest of my data is being alphabetically sorted by the fields in another column.  I want all the data to be sorted together with all of the NoneTypes together, either on top or below, not spaced throughout. Any help in figuring out how to custom sort this data would be much appreciated

EDIT: I added a custom parser

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({ 
    // set a unique id 
    id: 'enumsos', 
    is: function(s) { 
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
        return false; 
    }, 
    format: function(s) { 
        // format your data for normalization 
        return s.toString(); 
    }, 
    // set type, either numeric or text 
    type: 'text' 
}); 

$(function() { 
    $("table").tablesorter({ 
        headers: { 
            7: { 
                sorter:'enumsos' 
            } 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Now I'm running into a new problem, the sorting works but it only sorts my stuff descending, and this is for all columns! what's going on?

Comment: That's too bad. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Comment: Yes, my question is how can I have the column sort properly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure how the `47-123` value is to be sorted, but if you modify the parser to remove all non-digit values from the content (except decimal points), then only the numerical values will sort ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/4604/))

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    // set a unique id 
    id: 'enumsos',
    is: function (s) {
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
        return false;
    },
    format: function (s) {
        // format your data for normalization 
        return s.toString().replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
    },
    // set type, either numeric or text 
    type: 'numeric'
});

$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        headers: {
            0: {
                sorter: 'enumsos'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

as for the empty cells, you can set where they sort using the [`emptyTo` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#emptyto), or if that column contains non-numeric strings, like "N/A" then you can use the [`stringTo` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#stringto), but first the above parser would need to be modified to not replace all non-digits.